# Inserting part of webpage into another using html only

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I am trying to build a webpage using wix.com, and I want to include part of another website into mine. I can add html code. I am trying to get the featured poet on poetryoutloud.org into mine. This changed everyday and I only want this part of the webpage. I know that if I wanted to include the whole webpage I could use an iframe element, but this is only part of it

Answer (score 0):

You can use an iframe

or alternatively you can use ajax, here an example using jQuery.

```
$("#yoursite-html").load("yoursite-html.php");
```

Please note if content is on another domain as described in your answer (CORS issue), you have to use a simple proxy example below:

```
PHP in file "yoursite-html.php":

echo file_get_contents("http://www.yoursite.com/");
```